# authorization Error Error 400: invalid_request Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain. site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: ubuntu, login, google

I posted this question on overflow and they told me to post it here.
For some background: Im trying to use react-google-login on my react app in my AWS ubuntu server. I followed the advice given by others on similar stack exchange questions, and I could not arrive at a solution. In the place to enter the authorized URIs for oauth google, one user recommended to use a magic DNS service so that google would recognize the IP as a URI. If my public IP were 54.111.22.333:8080, I wrote it in as http://54.111.22.333.xip.io:8080 I received the same error. I even made an S3 storage button that redirected a true URL (a.b.org) to the IP, this didn't work. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I have no idea why they would send you here. Programming questions do indeed belong on [so].

Comment: With this level of detail, certainly not suitable for Stack Overflow. The cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014173/google-gives-error-of-authorization-error-error-400-invalid-request-permission certainly doesn't currently have any comments to suggest you should post here.